# Flurl and untrusted certificates

Tags: c#, .net, certificate, flurl

Currently I worked on Flurl and I tried to contact an API in https (I am in my lab).
So the certificate is not valid and Flurl can't continue to work :/

Here is my error message:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Call failed. The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception. POST https://IP/api/aaaLogin.json) ---> Flurl.Http.FlurlHttpException: Call failed. The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception. POST https://IP/api/aaaLogin.json ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception. ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.
```

In Flurl documentation we can use `using Flurl.Http.Configuration;` and modify the `DefaultHttpClientFactory` However I do not understand the elements specified to say of jumped over the errors.

On the web I can see the same case: https://github.com/tmenier/Flurl/issues/365 
Do you have an issue for this problem?

Thank you!

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The most typical way to do this is to [create a custom factory](https://flurl.dev/docs/configuration/#httpclientfactory):

```
public class UntrustedCertClientFactory : DefaultHttpClientFactory
{
    public override HttpMessageHandler CreateMessageHandler() {
        return new HttpClientHandler {
            ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (_, _, _, _) => true
        };
    }
}
```

Then register it somewhere in your app startup:

```
FlurlHttp.ConfigureClient("https://theapi.com", cli =>
    cli.Settings.HttpClientFactory = new UntrustedCertClientFactory());
```

Flurl reuses the same `HttpClient` instance per host by default, so configuring this way means that every call to `theapi.com` will allow the use of the untrusted cert. The advantage of this over passing an `HttpClient` to a `FlurlClient` constructor is that it keeps this configuration "off to the side" and works when you use Flurl in the more typical/less verbose way:

```
await "https://theapi.com/endpoint".GetJsonAsync();
```

Comment: Hi @ToddMenier thank you for this update. I only had to change the syntax.
`public class UntrustedCertClientFactory : DefaultHttpClientFactory
        {
            public override HttpMessageHandler CreateMessageHandler() => new HttpClientHandler
            {
                ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (a, b, c, d) => true
            };
        }`

Comment: @ToddMenier Is there any drawback to this change, perhaps client is vulnerable to attacks since bypassing Certificate validation callback, I am speculating

Comment: @Prateek The risks are exactly the same as doing it with a raw HttpClient. You'll need to determine whether it's appropriate for your situation.

Comment: I would do this strictly for unit tests or else restrict it to development and testing environments. Once you're in production, SSL certificates should be in place, or you're asking for trouble.

Answer (score 6):

Here is my setup for Flurl, which works with untrusted certificates:

```
HttpClientHandler httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
httpClientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (message, cert, chain, 
  errors) => true;
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler);
httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://myaddress.com");
var flurlClient = new FlurlClient(httpClient);

var apiInfo = await flurlClient.Request("apiInfo").GetJsonAsync<ApiInfoDto>();
```

I have created custom HttpClientHandler which accepts every certificate in `ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback`. Of course, you can use other logic in this handler.

**Update:**
With this setup, you cannot use Flurl extensions for URL (you cannot write `"http://myadress.com/apiInfo".GetJsonAsync<ApiInfoDto>()`. 
You have to create Flurl client as seen above and use Flurl client for your calls as demonstrated also in mine code. The usage is the same as Flurl extensions for URL.

Comment: Hi Karel, thank you for your support. it is therefore necessary to modify the values of HttpClientHandler what Flurl generates by default.
But your code is this present in the program class? Can you say me where apply this element? When you specify the new Uri is this the URL I am trying to contact?

Comment: @Digitag See my updated answer. In the real program, I initialiatize FlUrlClient at program startup and save it in some variable or property that is globally accessible (i.e. some kind of service). And then use it in the application.

Comment: @KarelKral This certainly works, but the alternative I've offered might have some advantages for you as well.

Answer (score 5):

An inline solution to accept any certificate is:

```cs
var myString = await "https://some-server-with-an-invalid-cert.net"
    .AppendPathSegment("/some-file.txt")
    .WithClient(new FlurlClient(new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler
              {
                  ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (message, cert, chain,
                                                               errors) => true
              })))
    .GetStringAsync();
```

With `WithClient()` you can pass a client configured different than the default client. In some cases you would not want to change the default client, but apply properties, e.g. the certificate validation only to this specific case.

Comment: Please provide a detailed explanation to your answer, in order for the next user to understand your answer better.